# Convert pivot table to sumif function - Error 424 - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I would like to convert a Pivot Table to a sum if statement using a VBA macro. 
I found one which used to work on Excel 2016 (https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/convert-pivot-table-to-sumifs-formulas-vba-macro/) since I went to 0365, the macro is not working.

I tried to fix the code myself but got stuck on the line

```
                Set rSource = Application.Evaluate(Application.ConvertFormula(PivotTable.SourceData, xlR1C1, xlA1))
```

which led to a #424 error object needed.

Any ideas would be gratefully accepted!

The whole code is the following`and the error seems to come from the function part:

```
Option Explicit
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim rSource As Range
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim bTable As Boolean
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim pc As PivotCell
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim wsNew As Worksheet
Dim wsPivot As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Dim lFunction As Long
Dim sSumRange As String
Dim sCritRange As String
Dim sCriteria As String
Dim sFormula As String
Dim sFormulaPage As String
Dim sSearchField As String
Dim sDataSheet As String
Dim lDataRows As Long
Dim sPageRange As String
Dim lCol As Long
Dim bArray As Boolean
Dim sTableName As String
Dim sFormulaArgs As String
Dim sFormulaCnt As String
Dim lLblRow As Long
Dim lLblCol As Long
Dim sFilter As String
Dim sDataField As String
Dim bReturn As Boolean

Sub Convert_Pivot_to_Formulas()
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : Convert_Pivot_to_Formulas
' Author    : Jon Acampora, Excel Campus LLC, www.excelcampus.com
' Date      : 10/13/2014
' Purpose   : Creates a copy of the selected pivot table on a new sheet and converts
'               all cells in the values area to SUMIFS, COUNTIFS, or AVERAGEIFS formulas
' Details   : The following is a list of features, requirement, and limitations of the macro.
'             Features
'               - Works with page fields with multiple items in filter of one page field.
'                   Creates the page field criteria across columns and creates array formulas.
'             Requirements
'               - Fields in the pivot containing dates must be in the same format as the source data.
'               - Source data must be in same workbook.  This can be expaned to ref source data in other workbooks.
'             Limitations
'               - Does not work with grouped date fields.  The criteria ranges do NOT exist in the source data.
'                   Create the date group fields as columns in the source data to solve this issue.
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'Set pivot table variables
    On Error Resume Next
    Set pvt = ActiveCell.PivotTable
    Set wsPivot = ActiveSheet
    On Error GoTo 0

    If pvt Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Please select a Pivot Table first.", vbOKOnly, "Convert Pivot to Formula Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Check if source data is in the same workbook.
    If Get_Pivot_Source Then

        On Error GoTo Err_Handle

'-------------------------------------------------------
'1. Create new sheet with shell of pivot table - filter, rows, columns areas
'-------------------------------------------------------
        Set wsNew = Worksheets.Add(after:=ActiveSheet)
        sDataSheet = wsSource.Name
        lDataRows = rSource.Rows.Count
        If bTable Then sTableName = pvt.SourceData

        'Copy pivot table values to new sheet
        wsPivot.Select
        wsPivot.Range(pvt.TableRange1.Address).Copy
        With wsNew.Range(pvt.TableRange1.Address)
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        End With

        If pvt.PageFields.Count > 0 Then
            wsPivot.Range(pvt.PageRange.Address).Copy
            With wsNew.Range(pvt.PageRange.Address)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
            End With
        End If

'-------------------------------------------------------
'2. Add page field filters across columns in new sheet
'-------------------------------------------------------
        If pvt.PageFields.Count > 0 Then
            For Each pf In pvt.PageFields
                sPageRange = pf.LabelRange.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 1).Address
                sFilter = pf.LabelRange.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 1).Value
                lCol = 0 'offset 1 col to the right
                Select Case sFilter
                    Case "(All)"
                        'skip
                    Case "(Multiple Items)"
                        'Loop pivot items and add selected items to page range across columns
                        For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
                            If pi.Visible Then
                                wsNew.Range(sPageRange).Offset(, lCol).Resize(1, 1).Value = pi.Name
                                lCol = lCol + 1
                            End If
                        Next pi
                    Case Else 'One item selected
                        lCol = 1
                        wsPivot.Range(sPageRange).Offset(, lCol).Resize(1, 1).Value = wsNew.Range(sPageRange).Offset(, lCol).Resize(1, 1).Value
                End Select

                'Create string for formula
                If lCol > 0 Then 'filters exist
                    If bTable Then
                        sCritRange = sTableName & "[" & pf.Name & "]"
                    Else
                        sSearchField = pf.Name
                        sCritRange = "'" & sDataSheet & "'!" & rSource.Resize(1).Find(What:=sSearchField, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(1).Resize(lDataRows - 1, 1).Address
                    End If

                    sCriteria = wsNew.Range(sPageRange).Resize(1, lCol).Address

                    sFormulaPage = sFormulaPage & "," & sCritRange
                    sFormulaPage = sFormulaPage & "," & sCriteria
                End If

                'IFS formula will have to be an array if there are multiple critera (range) in criteria argument
                If lCol > 1 Then bArray = True

            Next pf
        End If

'-------------------------------------------------------
'3. Loop through each cell in values area to build formula.
'-------------------------------------------------------
        For Each c In pvt.DataBodyRange.Cells

            Set pc = c.PivotCell
            sFormula = ""
            sFormulaArgs = ""

'-------------------------------------------------------
'4. Create SUM RANGE reference for formula
'-------------------------------------------------------
            'Check if function is sum, count, or average
            If pc.PivotField.Function = xlSum Or pc.PivotField.Function = xlCount Or pc.PivotField.Function = xlAverage Then
                'Count the criteria, if 0 then it's a total and no IFS needed
                sCriteria = ""

                'Add column items to filter array
                If pc.PivotCellType = xlPivotCellValue Then

                    sDataField = pc.PivotField.SourceName
                    lFunction = pc.PivotField.Function

                    'Add Sum Range
                    lFunction = pc.PivotField.Function

                    If bTable Then
                        sSumRange = sTableName & "[" & pc.PivotField.SourceName & "]"
                    Else
                        sSearchField = pc.PivotField.SourceName
                        sSumRange = "'" & sDataSheet & "'!" & rSource.Resize(1).Find(What:=sSearchField, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(1).Resize(lDataRows - 1, 1).Address
                    End If

'-------------------------------------------------------
'5. Loop through ROW items of pivotcell and add row refs to formula
'-------------------------------------------------------
                    If pc.RowItems.Count Then
                        For Each pi In pc.RowItems
                            If bTable Then
                                sCritRange = sTableName & "[" & pi.Parent.Name & "]"
                            Else
                                sSearchField = pi.Parent.Name
                                sCritRange = "'" & sDataSheet & "'!" & rSource.Resize(1).Find(What:=sSearchField, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(1).Resize(lDataRows - 1, 1).Address
                            End If

                            'Find the address of the pivotcells labelrange for the criteria address
                            'Start from the current row and loop up through the label range until the
                            'pivotitem name is found. Required due to variety of pivot table layouts.
                            lLblCol = pi.LabelRange.Column
                            For lLblRow = c.Row To pi.Parent.LabelRange.Row + 1 Step -1
                                If Cells(lLblRow, lLblCol).Value = pi.Name Then
                                    sCriteria = Cells(lLblRow, pi.LabelRange.Column).Address
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            Next lLblRow

                            If sCriteria <> "" Then
                                sFormulaArgs = sFormulaArgs & "," & sCritRange
                                sFormulaArgs = sFormulaArgs & "," & sCriteria
                            End If

                            sCriteria = ""

                        Next pi
                    End If

'-------------------------------------------------------
'6. Loop through COLUMN items of pivotcell and add row refs to formula
'-------------------------------------------------------
                    If pc.ColumnItems.Count Then
                        For Each pi In pc.ColumnItems
                            If bTable Then
                                sCritRange = sTableName & "[" & pi.Parent.Name & "]"
                            Else
                                sSearchField = pi.Parent.Name
                                sCritRange = "'" & sDataSheet & "'!" & rSource.Resize(1).Find(What:=sSearchField, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(1).Resize(lDataRows - 1, 1).Address
'                                If sCritRange Is Nothing Then
'                                On Error GoTo 0
'                                Else
'                            End If
                            End If

                            'Find the address of the pivotcells labelrange for the criteria address
                            'Start from the current column and loop back left through the label range until the
                            'pivotitem name is found. Required due to variety of pivot table layouts.
                            lLblRow = pi.LabelRange.Row
                            For lLblCol = c.Column To pi.LabelRange.Column Step -1
                                If Cells(lLblRow, lLblCol).Value = pi.Name Then
                                    sCriteria = Cells(pi.LabelRange.Row, lLblCol).Address
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            Next lLblCol

                            If sCriteria <> "" Then
                                sFormulaArgs = sFormulaArgs & "," & sCritRange
                                sFormulaArgs = sFormulaArgs & "," & sCriteria
                            End If

                            sCriteria = ""
                        Next pi
                    End If

'-------------------------------------------------------
'7. Build Formula based on function type of pivotcell
'-------------------------------------------------------
                    Select Case pc.PivotField.Function
                        Case xlSum
                            If sFormulaArgs = "" And sFormulaPage = "" Then 'Don't need IFS when there are no criteria (total rows/columns)
                                sFormula = "=SUM(" & sSumRange & ")"
                            Else
                                If bArray Then
                                    sFormula = "=SUM(SUMIFS(" & sSumRange & sFormulaPage & sFormulaArgs & "))"
                                Else
                                    sFormula = "=SUMIFS(" & sSumRange & sFormulaPage & sFormulaArgs & ")"
                                End If
                            End If

                        Case xlCount
                            If sFormulaArgs = "" And sFormulaPage = "" Then 'Don't need IFS when there are no criteria (total rows/columns)
                                sFormula = "=COUNT(" & sSumRange & ")"
                            Else
                                sFormulaCnt = sFormulaPage & sFormulaArgs 'Don't need sum range for countifs
                                sFormulaCnt = Right(sFormulaCnt, Len(sFormulaCnt) - 1) 'trim preceding comma

                                If bArray Then
                                    sFormula = "=SUM(COUNTIFS(" & sFormulaCnt & "))"
                                Else
                                    sFormula = "=COUNTIFS(" & sFormulaCnt & ")"
                                End If
                            End If

                        Case xlAverage
                            If sFormulaArgs = "" And sFormulaPage = "" Then 'Don't need IFS when there are no criteria (total rows/columns)
                                sFormula = "=AVERAGE(" & sSumRange & ")"
                            Else
                                sFormula = "=AVERAGEIFS(" & sSumRange & sFormulaPage & sFormulaArgs & ")" 'AVERAGEIFS not working with array formula, returns errors
                            End If

                    End Select

'-------------------------------------------------------
'8. Add formula to new sheet
'-------------------------------------------------------
                    If bArray Then
                        If Len(sFormula) < 255 Then
                            wsNew.Range(c.Address).FormulaArray = sFormula
                        Else
                            '.FormulaArray hits an error if formula string is > 255 characters
                            'Add error handling here
                        End If
                    Else
                        wsNew.Range(c.Address).Formula = sFormula
                    End If

                End If
            End If
        Next c

    End If

    wsNew.Select

    Exit Sub

Err_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbNewLine & "Current Cell: " & c.Address, _
            vbCritical, "Convert Pivot to Formulas Error"

End Sub
Function Get_Pivot_Source() As Boolean
'Determine if source is a cell reference, named range, or Excel Table
'Set source range variables

'Consider using the PivotCache.SourceType property to check this.
'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194557.aspx

    'On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    'Set variables for selected pivot table
    bReturn = False
    Set rSource = Nothing
    Set wsSource = Nothing
    Set pvt = ActiveCell.PivotTable
    Set wsPivot = ActiveSheet
    bTable = False

    If ActiveCell.PivotTable.PivotCache.SourceType = xlDatabase Then
        If InStr(ActiveCell.PivotTable.SourceData, "[") = 0 Then 'check if source data contains workbook name - bypass external source range - Temp TO DO
            If InStr(ActiveCell.PivotTable.SourceData, ":") > 0 Then 'if data source range is a cell ref range
                Set rSource = Application.Evaluate(Application.ConvertFormula(ActiveCell.PivotTable.SourceData, fromReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, toReferenceStyle:=xlA1))
            Else 'if Table or Named Range are used as data source range
                Set rSource = Range(pvt.SourceData)
                On Error GoTo SkipTable 'check if the data source name is a table
                Set rSource = Range(pvt.SourceData & "[#All]")
                bTable = True
SkipTable:
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
            Set wsSource = rSource.Parent
            bReturn = True
        End If
    End If

    Get_Pivot_Source = bReturn

    Exit Function

Err_Handler:

    MsgBox "Error in Get_Source_Range procedure."
    Get_Pivot_Source = False

End Function
```

Comment: Where is `PivotTable` defined? Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module.

Comment: Yes it is true. It tried it already but did not work.

Comment: What did you try, because you seem to be using `pvt` everywhere else.

Comment: I tried to add option explicit at the top of the module and in the function part I also did add the Dim pvt As PivotTable
What I did not understand is that sometime I got the error 91 on the line :    ```` If pvt.PivotCache.SourceType = xlDatabase Then````

Comment: Error 91 means you're trying to make a member call against an object reference that's `Nothing`. Verify whether `Not pvt Is Nothing` before you invoke its `.PivotCache` property, and verify that the returned `PivotCache` object isn't `Nothing` either, before you invoke its `SourceType` property.

Comment: *21, not 22. "assignment not used" inspection is issuing a false positive for the 1st `sFormulaPage` assignment (that's a known issue, it's not walking the syntax tree correctly here).

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot this is Christmas before time! Thanks to you, the code is running for pivot table based on a table as data source range but not on pivot table which using  cell ref range as data source. 
This means the error is coming from
```
Set rSource = Application.Evaluate(Application.ConvertFormula(ActiveCell.PivotTable.SourceData, fromReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, toReferenceStyle:=xlA1))````

I have the error 424 again on that line 
I have updated the first post with the up to date code

Comment: Ok is did a stop at each part of the macro and the fact is on my vba editor, the application.convertFormula does not translate the R1C1 style to A1 which is the reason of the error. Perhaps a manual translation would work!